# Access Form - Loop through series of labels and change the caption

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form with a series of labels, lbWeight1 through lbWeight20. Is there a way with VBA to loop through each and set the caption to "0"? Currently I have 20 lines of:

`lbWeight1.Caption = "0"`

One for each label. My method works, just looking for a better solution if possible.

Comment: There are many ways to do this: you could use the control's `Tag` property to tag it with something meaningful. Then, make a loop that loops through all controls on the form and checks the `.Tag` property for your tag. If it is a match, then change the caption to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you have things set up. If its on a button or on load. But this may work for what you are trying to do.

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click()


Dim x As Integer

For x = 1 To 20

    Me("lbWeight" & x).Caption = "0"        

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: @Gustav Just out of curiosity. Why the quotations around the 0? I understand you need them for letters but numbers work without them.

Comment: Because property `Caption` is of data type String.

Comment: The field is reset to "0" if an operator changes the product they are producing. When the ID field is updated, this code will run.

Comment: Ok, Roger that.

Comment: @Gustav - This code with the addition of 3 lines allowed me to get rid of 200 lines of code.

Comment: Great! Love to hear that. Then please mark as answered.